# Google analytics iOS campaign tracking testing on development

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm trying to use Google analytics iOS campaign tracking for my iOS app, but before uploading my app to the Appstore I would like to know if things are working properly...

I would like to put a breakpoint at the following function

```
application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

and see if I get the correct campaign name and see if it uploads correctly to google analytics...

But I couldn't find anything about testing it on development...

Any ideas?

Comment: I looking for this answer too. You got any luck ?

Comment: I am looking for this answer too, any thing new ?

Comment: have you guys got any success?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running GA in debug mode: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/advanced#testing

Then just access the app through one of your tracked campaigns and see if the data is recorded correctly.

Comment: have you guys got any success