# ios Google Analytics campaign tracking

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

i set up Google Analytics for my iOS-App and it is basically working fine (Screen Tracking, Purchases,...), except the install Campaign tracking is not ok.
I saw a similar question here which is not solved: 
[Google analytics iOS campaign tracking testing on development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428224/google-analytics-ios-campaign-tracking-testing-on-development)

This is the guide i used to implement (is in Objective-C):
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#general-campaigns

I see in my Google Analytics Dashboard the referrer installs, but no campaign installs.

This is a test Url

[https://click.google-analytics.com/redirect?tid=UA-51157298-2&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fat%2Fapp%2Fbikersos-motorrad-unfall-sos%2Fid980886530&aid=com.BikerApps.BikerSOS&idfa=%{idfa}&cs=test_source&cm=test_medium&cn=test_campaign&cc=test_campaign_content&ck=test_term](https://click.google-analytics.com/redirect?tid=UA-51157298-2&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fat%2Fapp%2Fbikersos-motorrad-unfall-sos%2Fid980886530&aid=com.BikerApps.BikerSOS&idfa=%25%7Bidfa%7D&cs=test_source&cm=test_medium&cn=test_campaign&cc=test_campaign_content&ck=test_term)

which i generated here: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder

My Code which should track the install is the following:

AppDelegate:

```
//Method where app parses any URL parameters used in the launch
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    //Track google Analytics URL
    GAService.shared.trackURL(url)

    //some other handlers here ....
    return true/false
}
```

GAService Singleton:

```
@objc public class GAService : NSObject {
private let trackID : String = "UA-xxxxxx-x"

var trackGoogleAnalytics : Bool = Constants.Analytics.trackGoogleAnalytics
private let UTM_SOURCE_KEY : String = "xxx"
private let UTM_MEDIUM_KEY : String = "xxx"
private let UTM_CAMPAIGN_KEY : String = "xxx"
var trackUncaughtExceptions : Bool = true
var tracker : GAITracker? = nil

static let shared = GAService()

var UtmSource : String {
    get {
        if let utm = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UTM_SOURCE_KEY) {
            return utm
        }
        return ""
    }
    set {
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UTM_SOURCE_KEY) == nil {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UTM_SOURCE_KEY)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }
}
var UtmCampaign : String {
    get {
        if let utm = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UTM_CAMPAIGN_KEY) {
            return utm
        }
        return ""
    }
    set {
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UTM_CAMPAIGN_KEY) == nil {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UTM_CAMPAIGN_KEY)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }
}
var UtmMedium : String {
    get {
        if let utm = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UTM_MEDIUM_KEY) {
            return utm
        }
        return ""
    }
    set {
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UTM_MEDIUM_KEY) == nil {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UTM_MEDIUM_KEY)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }
}
private override init() {
    super.init()

    if(trackGoogleAnalytics) {
        tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().tracker(withTrackingId: trackID)
        tracker!.allowIDFACollection = true

        GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = trackUncaughtExceptions
        GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.error
        GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 1
    }
}

public func trackURL(_ url : URL){
    let urlString = url.absoluteString
    // setCampaignParametersFromUrl: parses Google Analytics campaign ("UTM")
    // parameters from a string url into a Map that can be set on a Tracker.
    let hitParams : GAIDictionaryBuilder = GAIDictionaryBuilder()

    // Set campaign data on the map, not the tracker directly because it only
    // needs to be sent once.
    hitParams.setCampaignParametersFromUrl(urlString)

    // Campaign source is the only required campaign field. If previous call
    // did not set a campaign source, use the hostname as a referrer instead.
    if((hitParams.get(kGAICampaignSource) != nil) && (url.host ?? "").length() != 0) {
        hitParams.set("referrer", forKey: kGAICampaignMedium)
        hitParams.set(url.host, forKey: kGAICampaignSource)
    }
    let hitParamsDict : [AnyHashable : Any] =  hitParams.build() as Dictionary as [AnyHashable : Any]

    if(hitParamsDict.count > 0) {
        // A screen name is required for a screen view.
        let source : String? = hitParams.get(kGAICampaignSource)
        let medium : String? = hitParams.get(kGAICampaignMedium)
        let campaign : String? =  hitParams.get(kGAICampaignName)
        if(source != nil || medium != nil || campaign != nil) {
            tracker?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "openUrl")
            GAService.shared.UtmSource = source ?? ""
            GAService.shared.UtmMedium = medium ?? ""
            GAService.shared.UtmCampaign = campaign ?? ""
        }

        // SDK Version 3.08 and up.
        //[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] setAll:hitParamsDict] build]];
        let sendDict : [AnyHashable : Any] =  GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().setAll(hitParamsDict).build() as Dictionary as [AnyHashable : Any]
        tracker?.send(sendDict)
        tracker?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: nil)
    }
}
```

As i have to set a screenName for such a tracking i defined openUrl as a constant and set it to nil afterwards i sent the dictionary.

I hope anybody can see what i'm doing wrong

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I used it with deep link where I decide the navigation:

```
let tracker1 = GAI.sharedInstance().tracker(withTrackingId: "...")
            let hitParams = GAIDictionaryBuilder()
            hitParams.setCampaignParametersFromUrl(path)
            let medium = self.getQueryStringParameter(url: path, param: "utm_medium")

            hitParams.set(medium, forKey: kGAICampaignMedium)
            hitParams.set(path, forKey: kGAICampaignSource)

            let hitParamsDict = hitParams.build()

            tracker1?.allowIDFACollection = true

            tracker1?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "...")
            tracker1?.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().setAll(hitParamsDict as? [AnyHashable : Any]).build() as? [AnyHashable : Any])

// this is for url utm_medium parameter

/*
func getQueryStringParameter(url: String, param: String) -> String? {
    guard let url = URLComponents(string: url) else { return nil }
    return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
}*/
```

then I saw the source on google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Google Analytics docs are very poor on this subject. If you look carefully in what is written in the main guide for "Campaign Measurement" it says *"After an app has been installed, it may be launched by referrals from ad campaigns, websites, or other apps"* and Google gives an example with custom url scheme which is handled.

Hopefully, there is another guide https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/mobile-campaign-deep-link which describes how to use deep linking for campaign measurement.

So, if you want to track campaign measurement you must use either **Universal Links mechanism** or **custom url scheme** for your application.

Universal Links mechanism is the preferred way if you have backend and hence can decide where to redirect user: in iTunes or in application.

Assume, you have a site link *https://example.com/openapp* which redirects user to iTunes Connect. You should insert you Universal Link address (*https://example.com/openapp*) in the 
generator https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder.